# How can I delete virtual networks from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 (without GUI) running at my colo for a week.

I was connected via RDP and could use the menu interface and command line. I figured out how to connect Hyper-V Manager from my Win7 laptop (THANK YOU HVREMOTE!), and created and installed my VM.
I created a virtual network that didn't work (no connectivity from my VM) so I created another using different settings, and now have lost access to the Hyper-V host. No ping, no RDP.

Since I don't have console access, I cannot troubleshoot. I believe if I deleted the Virtual Networks I'd regain access, but I need a command line instruction for this, that the staff onsite could enter to accomplish this.

I find no help anywhere obvious (MSDN, etc), the keywords are too general.

Can anyone refer me to simple steps how to do this over command line or with the menu based interface on the console?

Comment: You probably created a Virtual Network that is connected to the Machine's NIC, but isn't connected to the Management OS. This will leave the Management OS disconnected. You'll need physical (or pseudo physical) access to the machine to fix it. Call your hosting company. The onsite staff are required to be trained in how to fix this (must be MS Partners to get the SPLA license).

Comment: Ancient topic I know, but from the OPs question it wouldnt appear he would need to be at a licensed/partnered COLO to run "Hyper-V Server 2008 R2"

Answer (score -1):

More research...
I found something related here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/708aef60-05ad-40ed-af70-5ddcaf2a7a36

Referring to a tool called nvspscrub on the code.msdn.microsoft.com site.

I'll give this a try.

Comment: and it worked! ran nvspscrub.js /p and I can now ping and rdp

Comment: Please elaborate in this answer what the link says. Links may change over time.

Answer (score -1):

For scripting Hyper-V, there are two blogs that really help.

First is Ben Armstrong's.  I just typed in a search for "switch script" and the first five or so entries were helpful.  They were all about creating virtual networks from the command line, but you'll be able to extrapolate their removal.

http://blogs.msdn.com/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=switch%20script&sections=4122

The second is John Howard's blog.  I just typed the same query into his search box and the first result is highly relevant.

http://blogs.technet.com/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=switch%20script&sections=4098

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please elaborate in your answer why the links are relevant/has good informations. Links may change over time.